# Check the file type returned by an HTTP GET request

Tags: javascript, iframe, sapui5

You would think my problem would be so commonplace that there would be solutions all over the internet for it. But I can't find anything that really answers my question.

Let me summarise my situation:

- I am using Open UI5.
- I am coding an app which retrieves documents from various external websites. I want to display these documents inside my app, and not navigate to them, so I display the documents in an iframe. Haven't found any other way.
- Some filetypes can be displayed natively, such as PDFs. Others, like Word, cannot - the easiest way I have found of displaying these is by using Google Docs, which implies changing the URL of the iframe's src from this :

*http://example.com/my-target-doc.docx*

to this:

*http://docs.google.com/gview?url=example.com/my-target-doc.docx&embedded=true*

- Some of the external domains I retrieve the documents from require authentication. Therefore, I cannot set the iframe's src to *http://docs.google.com/gview?url=example.com/my-target-doc.docx&embedded=true* directly - Google docs would attempt to display the authentication page. I must keep the original URL, and then, once the user's authenticated, replace the document URL with the Google docs version of the same URL.
- What I am trying to do, then, is use the iframe's "onload" event to get the currently loaded page's address and, if it is a .doc/.docx/.ppt etc, replace that same URL with the GD version of the URL.
- The difficulty is that there is no extension at the end of the URL which points to the document - none of the URLs I need to use end with ".doc", ".ppt" or whatever, so parsing the URL is out.

So this is my question : Is there a way in Javascript to get the type of the content being returned? To be fair, I am pretty doubtful there is. Other ideas or alternatives are welcome. I am still actively looking for some.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Did you already look at the [Content-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) HTTP header? This can be read with JS, but you probably have to request the file asynchronously for that.

Comment: No, I didn't. The difficulty here is that I don't manually send explicitly send the HTTP requests, they happen when navigation occurs inside the iframe. Maybe I can find some way of intercepting the requests and changing them according to the Content-type which comes back, although I doubt the browser's security constraints will allow it.

Comment: Could you try to perform the request asynchronously (e.g. with jQuery's `.get`)? Based on the content type you can then do the appropriate redirect.

Comment: I'm looking into jQuery at the moment. I'll try and figure it out over the weekend - I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in getting back to you - I am changing the design slightly, I am not going to go down this route anymore. It's just too fiddly to try and mess with an iframe because it goes against the whole idea behind it. Thanks for your help nonetheless.